# What does this bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, partitioning, gentoo

In theory, this snippet from pentoo-installer finds all partitions on the selected disc, but it doesn't find my sda1 partition, so I would love to understand it and modify so it does.

```
findpartitions() {
    workdir="$PWD"
    for devpath in $(finddisks); do
        disk=$(echo $devpath | sed 's|.*/||')
        cd /sys/block/$disk
        for part in $disk*; do
            # check if not already assembled to a raid device
            if ! [ "$(cat /proc/mdstat 2>/dev/null | grep $part)" -o "$(fstype 2>/dev/null </dev/$part | grep "lvm2")" -o "$(sfdisk -c /dev/$disk $(echo $part | sed -e "s#$disk##g") 2>/dev/null | grep "5")" ]; then
                if [ -d $part ]; then
                    echo "/dev/$part"
                    [ "$1" ] && echo $1
                fi
            fi
        done
    done

    #[ ... more code ...]

    cd "$workdir"
}
```

Thanks!!

Comment: What is `$(finddisks)` ?

Comment: It is another bash function. It is in the pentoo-installer script: https://code.google.com/p/pentoo/source/browse/pentoo-installer/trunk/sbin/pentoo-installer

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to [debug this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21190771/how-to-properly-debug-a-bash-script) a bit. For starters, add echo commands to dump the flow and optionally the variables after each for loop and if statement.

Are you able to [run the command with debug turned on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951336/how-to-debug-a-bash-script)? That will provide you with just about the same level of details an help you understand what the flow of the script is doing in reality. Also, this post on unix explains how to get line numbers out of the debug that bash has provided us.

- https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/155551/how-to-debug-a-bash-script

Comment: Thanks, I would debug it for sure, but in a lack of time I thought that I would ask for orientation mainly on the long line that makes several checks.

Comment: @user464121 If you really only need help with that one line, edit your post to break that one down. The easier you make it for someone to ignore most of the script, the more likely we will do the work for you :-) You might get a bunch of grizzled veterans that shrug and let you learn to fish instead of catching you the one you seek, though.